# How to upload image file from Android to ASP.NET(Web Services- ASMX) upload folder using Retrofit

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, retrofit

Please help me to provide me the solution for that because I have tried many codes and I had referred many tutorials but everyone shows different results.

So please help me, anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can try Using Koush ION, [Here is the GitHub](https://github.com/koush/ion), also can you expand your question is there any errors what is the problem exactly ......next time you ask a question you should add code snippets and a full explaination of the issue... you will have a better chance of recieving a answer.....SO in koush ION its easy to use implement the library with

```
implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1
```

and then call it with

```
 Ion.with(SecondActivity.this)
                .load(myURL)-Enter your URL here
                .uploadProgressDialog(pd)
                .setMultipartFile("pdf","pdf/*",filePath )-here you set the type and location of the file
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() { - here you get results from the server using a json array/object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        String message = result.get("message").getAsString();
                        Toasty.info(SecondActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();-here i use the Toasty library for awesome looking toast messages
```